# remove duplicates in Set

Tags: java, collections, duplicates, set, hashset

How can I avoid inserting duplicate elements in a Set? If I have:

```
 Set<User> user=new HashSet<>();
                            User user1=new User("11","Mark",null,"1");
                            User user2=new User("11","Mark",null,"1");
                            User user3=new User("12","Helen",null,"2");

                            user.add(user1);
                            user.add(user2);
                            Log.d("main_activity_user", "la dimensione è" +String.valueOf(user.size()));
```

Adn User class is:

```
public class User {
    public String uid;
public String name;
    public String pversion;
public String upicture;
    public User(String uid,
            String name,
                String upicture, String pversion ){
        this.uid=uid;
        this.name=name;
        this.upicture=upicture;
        this.pversion=pversion;
    }
    public String get_uid(){
        return uid;
    }
    public String get_name(){
        return name;
    }
    public String get_pversion(){
        return pversion;
    }
    public String get_upicture(){
        return upicture;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        User newObj = (User)obj;
        if (this.get_uid().equals( newObj.get_uid()))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

Now the `Set` also stores duplicates and prints me 3 elements instead of two. Why?

I have never used the `Set` class before and I don't understand it. So, every time I use the `Set` class, do I have to Override the Equals method? Why? Doesn't the class delete duplicates automatically?

Comment: Did you override `hashCode()`?

Comment: so for this we use the equals method? because every time I add an element to Set this is compared with the others with the Equals method? right? But I have used the Equals () method in the User class and it does not eliminate the duplicates , why?

Comment: You have to override `hashCode()` in conjunction with `equals(Object)`. Besides that, you should test with `instanceof` before casting to `User`. Further, don’t write `if(condition) return true; else return false;` Just write `return condition;`. Further, don’t write `"string" + String.valueOf(expression)`. You can simply write `"string" + expression`.

Comment: In java there is contract between `equals` and `hashCode`.
This tutorial explains well, why your code works, as it is working now: https://www.baeldung.com/java-equals-hashcode-contracts

Comment: Many things slightly wrong with your code. You should always override hashCode() and equals() together, especially when thinking about HASH sets. Then follow java naming conventions. Do NOT use the "_" in your variable or method names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it has been already said in the comments, your `User` class needs to honor the hashcode and equals contracts by overriding the `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()

In your code, you're using a `HashSet`, which is implemented as a `HashMap` under the hood. A `HashMap`, instead, is implemented as an array of buckets, where each entry is stored within a bucket based on the key's `hashCode()`. However, different keys may yield the same hashcode, so multiple entries may be listed within a same bucket. In order to reference the right entry within a bucket, a `HashMap` has to resort to the key's `equals()` method to find the exact entry whose key matches the given value. This sequence of operations is performed, for example, when an element is retrieved or replaced. Lastly, a bucket is a generic data structure. In Java, `HashMap`'s buckets were implemented as `LinkedList` up to Java 7, while from Java 8 on, it is employed a hybrid solution where after a certain number of collisions the `LinkedList` implementation is switched to a Balanced Tree. For more details, read the [JEP-180](https://openjdk.org/jeps/180).

This brief explanation shows you why it is so crucial to provide a proper definition of the `hashCode()` and `equals()` methods, because, as you can see, a `HashMap` heavily relies on these methods.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html

Here is a proper implementation of your `User` class, where two users are said identical if they have the same: `uid`, `name`, `pversion` and `upicture`. Instead, if two users are identical only by some of the mentioned fields, then you should update the `equals()` and `hashCode()` implementations accordingly (both of them must be based on the same fields).

```
public class User {
    public String uid;
    public String name;
    public String pversion;
    public String upicture;

    public User(String uid, String name, String upicture, String pversion) {
        this.uid = uid;
        this.name = name;
        this.upicture = upicture;
        this.pversion = pversion;
    }

    public String getUid() {
        return uid;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getPversion() {
        return pversion;
    }

    public String getUpicture() {
        return upicture;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        User user = (User) o;
        return Objects.equals(uid, user.uid) && Objects.equals(name, user.name) && Objects.equals(pversion, user.pversion) && Objects.equals(upicture, user.upicture);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(uid, name, pversion, upicture);
    }
}
```

##### Test Main

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Set<User> user = new HashSet<>();
        User user1 = new User("11", "Mark", null, "1");
        User user2 = new User("11", "Mark", null, "1");
        User user3 = new User("12", "Helen", null, "2");

        user.add(user1);
        user.add(user2);
        System.out.println("Size is: " + user.size());
    }
}
```

##### Output

```
Size is: 1
```

Comment: thank you very much i will also implement equals () and hacode()